Redis search ft.aggregate with reduction on multiple fields
I have schema users on which I have created index using ft.create.
The schema (and index) contains fields like user_id, user_name, user_contact_type, user_contact_content.
There might be several entries for the same user.
I need to construct search query that will return a user with list of contacts, the list of contacts should have contact_type together with contact_content (e.g. adress:some_city, email:email@email.com)
After reading documentation ft.aggregate looks promising, but I am not able to return the list that is grouped by user_id having several entries with both contact_type and contact_conten
I was trying tolist reduction like this:
`127.0.0.1:6379> ft.aggregate users_idx '@user_name: adam'  groupby 1 @user_id reduce tolist 2 contact_id contact_content dialect 3

(integer) 1


"user_id"
"33b60427-9fdf-47e1-b6df-d833e3703e4d"
"__generated_aliastolistcontactid"


"574de6cf-e9c7-3134-a7da-0e66960ee994"
"879f4e89-c2df-3d23-b4ed-4fca37248ae8"
"8e9c7702-fcdf-327e-b869-47aa4299c4b6"
"04bdf34a-67d3-308a-844a-6d9efdbf77e4"
"d9bfff8c-36f7-3fba-a072-725128f489b5"`





It looks like tolist reduction accepts only one field.
Is it possible to have results like:
1) (integer) 1 2) 1) "user_id" 2) "33b60427-9fdf-47e1-b6df-d833e3703e4d" 3) "__generated_aliastolistcontactid" 4) 1) "574de6cf-e9c7-3134-a7da-0e66960ee994 adam@gmail.com" 2) "879f4e89-c2df-3d23-b4ed-4fca37248ae8 +43 21234 221" 3) "8e9c7702-fcdf-327e-b869-47aa4299c4b6 Downning street" 4) "04bdf34a-67d3-308a-844a-6d9efdbf77e4 Ebay.com" 5) "d9bfff8c-36f7-3fba-a072-725128f489b5 house X"
So I would like to have result from reduction to be some kind of concatenation of several fields (2 in may case).
Having multiple tolist reductions I am getting results that are with no order - the contact_id doesn't matche the contact_content from the same index entry (they're mixed).
`127.0.0.1:6379> ft.aggregate users_idx '@user_name: adam'  groupby 2 @user_id @user_name reduce tolist 1 @contact_id reduce tolist 1 @contact_content as xx limit 0 10

(integer) 1


"user_id"
"33b60427-9fdf-47e1-b6df-d833e3703e4d"
"user_name"
"5b3ca70c-c584-409f-93a8-6f24b9b0a850"
"__generated_aliastolistcontactid"


"5ef6be2d-59f4-4652-a680-585929924ba9"
"47c05422-5379-4c27-9ddf-e02b52b3d961"
"85760831-0671-4127-93f7-0eee227c5ff9"
"519a2d12-d099-434a-a3a2-a7397db7c741"
"5d13e891-162a-456b-abf2-fd9b864df96d"


"xx"




"Downning street"
"adam@gmail.com"
"Ebay.com"
"+43 21234 221"
"house X"`



The thing is that values from __generated_aliastolistcontactid and xx lists do not match - value from particular index of __generated_aliastolistcontactid does not match value of xx list at the same index.
Is it possible what I want to achieve using a single ft.aggregate call?
Or maybe is it possible to have 2 layers of group/reduce to have this result:

(integer) 1


"user_id"
"33b60427-9fdf-47e1-b6df-d833e3703e4d"
"user_name"
"5b3ca70c-c584-409f-93a8-6f24b9b0a850"
"__generated_aliastolistcontactid"


"5ef6be2d-59f4-4652-a680-585929924ba9"

"Downning street"


"47c05422-5379-4c27-9ddf-e02b52b3d961"

"adam@gmail.com"


"85760831-0671-4127-93f7-0eee227c5ff9"

"Ebay.com"


"519a2d12-d099-434a-a3a2-a7397db7c741"

"+43 21234 221"


"5d13e891-162a-456b-abf2-fd9b864df96d"

"house X"







